# How is this code working?? val3 is defined as constant

Tags: arduino-uno

```
const int val3 = 7;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int val3 = 8;
  int val4 = 4;
  Serial.print(calc(val3,val4));
}

void loop() 
{}

int calc(int val1, int val2)
{
  return val1 + val2;
}
```

this code gives output as 12.

Comment: print val3 in loop()

Comment: I did not get you, can you explain again.

Comment: you use the second `int val3` defined in setup(). it shadows the global val3

Comment: @Akash, add a Serial.print() statement into the loop() block ... print out the value of val3 ... what prints in the serial monitor?

Answer (score 3):

In your code, the `const int val3 = 7;` definition, is outside of any functions so it defines a **global** constant/variable (available in every part of your code).

The `int val3 = 8;` definition is inside your `setup ()` function, so it acts as a **local** variable only within that function. This overrides the `val3` constant defined outside of the `setup ()` function. I.e. the global `val3` constant and the local `val3` variable inside of `setup ()` are not the same variable, which will inevitably lead to confusion (as in your case).

It’s valid syntax but I don’t consider it good coding practice. It’s good to know why it works that way though.

Comment: Thanx, i got it.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared val3 two times: One time as constant int and another time as int (in setup loop). Replace the statement `int val3=8 by val3 = 8`. You will know the difference.

The first declaration is of no use in this case. As a try, you may first declare val3 as int and in the second declaration you may declare val3 as const int.

Just try and note the difference. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanx, i got it.